# How to merge 2 BIG Tables into 1 adding up existing values with PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have 2 big tables (1 has 690K Rows, 2nd one has 890K rows).
They have the same format and columns:

```
Username - Points - Bonuses - COLUMN D... COLUMN - K.
```

Lets say in the first table i have the "Original" usernames and in the 2nd table i have "New" usernames + Some of the "Original" usernames (So people who are still playing + people who are new to the game).

What I'm trying to do is to merge them so i can have in a single table (sum up) their values.

I've already made my tables proper System Tables.
I created their connection in the workbook.
I've tried to merge them but i keep getting less rows than i expect to have, so some records are being left out or not being summed.
I've tried Left Outer, Right Outer, Full Outer with no success.

This is where im standing:

[image]

Comment: You may well run out of rows. Excel taps out at just over a million. I'd consider something different if you have that much data.

Comment: If your tables have the same columns, you would want to append the tables instead of merge.  Alternatively, you could leave the tables separate and load to Excel as a connection only (not to a ws), and add to the data model.   From there, you can launch Power Pivot, create a relationship that connects the two tables and then have the data displayed on an Excel worksheet as a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jenn said, i had to append the tables instead of merging them and i also used a filter inside PowerQuery to remove all blanks/zeros before loading it into Excel, i was left with 500K Unique rows, instead of 1.6 Million. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I would append the tables, as indicated above. First load each table separately into PowerQuery, and then append one table into the other one. The column names look a little long and it may make sense to simplify the column names so that the system doesn't read them as different columns due to an inadvertent typo.